# how to iterate through the Unix command result in python script

Tags: python, linux, for-loop, unix

```
cmd=('~/bin/pelbase export_site -a HTTP_S_ER')
text=os.system(cmd)
for line in text:
  if line == 'xps_entity':
    entity=line
    print(line)
  elif line == 'xps_pass':
    entity=line
    print(line)
  elif line == 'xdest_addr':
    entity=line
    print(line)
  elif line == 'xmax_num':
    entity=line
    print(line)
  elif line == 'xlogin_mod':
    entity=line
    print(line)

#if the cmd result was like this 
BEGAN_SIT
s_alis='HTTP_WSD'
xps_entity='HTTP_S_ER'
xlogin_mod='http'
xdest_addr='sft.ftr.net'
xmax_num='99'
xps_pass='pass'
xparam_nm='htp'
#?SITE END
```

i was trying to iterate through this result but i got int object is not iterable error
how can i itrate through this command results to get one by one

Answer (score 0):

`os.system` does not return the text output of the command.  The output just goes to your terminal, and it returns the integer exit code.  You need `subprocess.check_output`.

Your code has other problems as well.  The line will never equal "xps_entity".  You need to parse it into pieces first.  Try this:

```
cmd = 'pelbase export_site -a HTTP_S_ER'
text = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
store = {}
for line in text:
  if '=' not in line:
    continue
  parts = line.split('=')
  store[parts[0]] = parts[1]

print(store)
```

Comment: what need from this is actually itrateate through the cmd results and assign each one for different variable one by one

Comment: Why do you feel you need separate variables?  The `dict` as used in this answer is an excellent and portable container from which the values can be extracted (indexed) easily when required; or even stored to a file if the need should arise.

Comment: because i want use these variables  to be inserted on db for the next step

Comment: I'm getting error [ERRNO2] no such a file or directory

Comment: `subprocess` doesn't expand the home directory tilde (`~`).  Since `~/bin` is usually on your path, I'll make a suggestion above.

Comment: I’m getting same error no such a file or directory

Comment: WHERE are you getting that error?

Comment: On the Unix server shell

Comment: What Unix server?  If you type that command at the command line, does it work?

Comment: Yeah it does work in command line

Comment: If it works when you type it at a command line, then it will work in a `subprocess` call.  It has to.  Are you running with `sudo`?  Is this all on the same computer?